# #1452 MySQL Error: alter table add foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables (cliente, usuario), when I try add foreign key for cliente, referencing table usuario, it is cause error 1452

```
Table Cliente

id          int             primary key     auto_increment
nome        varchar(50)     not null
telefone    varchar(14)
email       varchar(30)
id_usuario  int             not null

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table Usuario

id      int             primary key     auto_increment
nome    varchar(50)     not null
email   varchar(30)     not null
```

My alter table sql

```
ALTER TABLE cliente
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id);
```

Where is problem for cause this error?

error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pedidosystem`.`#sql-25ac_5f`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-25ac_5f_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id`))
```

Comment: You have a value in the `usuario_id` column that does not exist in the `usuario (id)` column.

Comment: great!! can you create a answer for me choose?

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter said, you have one or more rows in `cliente` with `id_usario` values that don't appear anywhere in `usario.id`.  You'll have to fix this before you create your foreign key constraint.

You can locate the offending records in `cliente` like this, before you create the fk.

```
SELECT cliente.*
  FROM cliente
  LEFT JOIN usario on cliente.usario_id = usario.id
 WHERE usario.id = NULL
```

Once you know which records are bad, you can update them or delete them.